# Helm Chart Metadata Dependency Issue with DAPR

Tags: terraform, terraform-helm-provider

I am trying to create a DAPR Deployment via helm:

```
resource "helm_release" "dapr" {
  depends_on = [module.primary]
  name       = "dapr"
  repository = "https://charts.wener.tech"
  chart      = "dapr"
  version    = "1.11.0"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  lint       = true
  timeout    = "600"

  values = ["${file("./values/dapr.values.yaml")}"]

  cleanup_on_fail = true
}
```

From the above helm chart I reference a values file within the same directory called `./values/dapr.values.yaml`:

```
global:
  logAsJson: true
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector: {}
  tolerations: []
  ha:
    enabled: false
    replicaCount: 3
    disruption:
      minimumAvailable: ""
      maximumUnavailable: "25%"
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
    port: 9090
  dapr_dashboard:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
        cpu: "50m"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
  dapr_operator:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
  dapr_placement:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "150Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "150Mi"
  dapr_sentry:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
  dapr_sidecar_injector:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
```

When I run the terraform, on the `terraform plan` it fails saying the following:

```
Error: malformed chart or values: 
    /tmp/helm-lint80298427/dapr: chart metadata is missing these dependencies: dapr_placement,dapr_rbac,dapr_sentry,dapr_sidecar_injector,dapr_config,dapr_operator
```

Yet, I have the dependencies mentioned within the `dapr.values.yaml`, why is it still failing? Is there something wrong with my `yaml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something is wrong with the chart. Essentially I had to take out the following out of the terraform block:

```
lint       = true
```

After I took that out, it defaulted to `false` as defined by `helm_release`, so the messages were obviously related to the linter utilized by the provider, and for some odd reason it didn't respect the chart values I placed in. Once I took it out, everything worked on `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` and the resources did deploy. So I guess `Linters Beware`.

The new block looks like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "dapr" {
  depends_on = [module.primary]
  name       = "dapr"
  repository = "https://dapr.github.io/helm-charts/"
  chart      = "dapr"
  version    = "1.10.7"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  timeout    = "600"

  values = ["${file("./values/dapr.values.yaml")}"]

  cleanup_on_fail   = true
  dependency_update = true
}
```

I also changed to using the other `dapr` repository. Apparently there are two main ones that seem to stem from the same place, but with `lint` set to true, it failed on both.